# R: mgcv function bam: use multiple kernels from jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, mgcv

I use R in a jupyter notebook as described in this [article](https://developers.refinitiv.com/en/article-catalog/article/setup-jupyter-notebook-r). It work's perfectly fine. However, when I fit a GAM using the `mgcv` library and `bam`, e.g.:

```
dat <- gamSim(1,n=25000,dist="normal",scale=20)
bs <- "cr"; k <- 12
b <- bam(y ~ s(x0,bs=bs)+s(x1,bs=bs)+s(x2,bs=bs,k=k)+
           s(x3,bs=bs), data=dat, discrete=TRUE, nthreads=4)
```

the jupyter notebook does not utilize multiple cpu's at once. This is problematic as work with big data. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `discrete = TRUE` to be able to use the `nthreads` argument. Read `?bam` for ways to do the computation in parallel if you don’t want to use the discretisation option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My fault. I use ```discrete=True``` in the notebook but forgot to include it in my question

Comment: @hyhno01 it's `TRUE` not `True`. Try running the code outside of a Jupyter notebook as that may be causing a problem. I believe nthreads requires the package to have been compiled with openMP support, so perhaps check that too?